# How to save multiple forms in on page in Django

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I am trying to make a betting app in Django. After a user signs in, there's a page with several forms, each responsible for saving the result of a match. Each form takes two integer inputs (number of goals for each team). I want to have a save button at the end of these forms such that when clicked, the input data are recorded in the database. I have two models, Game and Bet. Game is responsible for storing the actual result of games, while Bet is responsible for recording user predictions.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    team1_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team2_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team1_score = models.IntegerField()
    team2_score = models.IntegerField()

class Bet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    team1_score = models.IntegerField()
    team2_score = models.IntegerField()
```

And here's the main page

```html
{% for game in games %}
<form action="../place_bet/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-col"><label for="team1_score">{{ game.team1_name}}</label></th>
      <th class="table-col">{{ form.team1_score }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-col"><label for="team2_score">{{ game.team2_name}}</label></td>
      <td class="table-col">{{ form.team2_score }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how I can capture the input fields for different forms in the `place_bet` view that is triggered when submit button is clicked.

Comment: It sounds like you want 1 form with more fields as opposed to multiple forms.

Comment: @CarsonCrane I thought about that too, but don't you think things will get out of control when the number of games to be predicted gets large?

Answer (score 0):

***For a throughly answer about how to process multiple repeated fields with one form on Django, please read this answer history. This will be an answer on good practices to process many forms from one page in Django.***

So there's a recipe for this, what we will need is the following:

1. A View, it can be class-based or function-based, in this example, I'll use class-based because it's tidy.
2. An URL where this View is served, the only special thing about it is an optional parameter added to the end of it.
3. A template with the correct setup for calling the right view function.
4. Optionally, you can use a Form to validate the data, but it's not a requirement.

So, the first things first, let's create the View. This will separate concerns to better readability.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

class PlaceBet(View):
  template_name = 'place_bets.html'
  context = some_base_context_dict

  def get(self, request):
    # the user is requesting the game list
    self.context['games'] = Game.objects.all()
    return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

  def post(self, request, game_id=None):
    # the user is submitting one of game's predictions
    if not game_id:
      return HttpResponseBadRequest('hey, send a game id, you fool!')
    game = get_object_or_404(Game, pk=game_id)
    # here you can use a Form to validate the data, but hey,
    # do your homework
    bet = Bet.objects.create(user=request.user, game=game, 
                             team1_score=request.POST.get('team1_score'),
                             team2_score=request.POST.get('team2_score'))
    # bet is saved at this point so now we can now take the user
    # elsewhere or i dunno, the same page...
    self.context['games'] = Game.objects.all()
    self.context['new_bet'] = bet
    response = render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
    # it's good practice to say you created something
    response.status_code = 201
    return response
```

Now, the Urls need some work too, you're passing a parameter, so...

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^place_bet$', PlaceBet.as_view()),
  url(r'^place_bet/(?P<game_id>[^/.]+)', PlaceBet.as_view(), name='place-bet') #name parameter, very important for the future...
]
```

Your template is almost right, but it needs some work:

```
{% for game in games %}
<!-- the action now points to the URL by name, and passes the game_id -->
<form action="{% url 'place-bet' game.pk %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-col">
        <label for="team1_score">{{ game.team1_name}}</label>
      </th>
      <th class="table-col">
        <!-- you need something to submit -->
        <input type="number" name="team1_score" value="{{ game.team1_score }}">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-col">
        <label for="team2_score">{{ game.team2_name}}</label>
      </td>
      <td class="table-col">
        <input type="number" name="team2_score" value="{{ game.team2_score }}">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

And there it is, now when you press the Submit button, the browser will send the POST data to the `post` method of the view, using an action URL that encodes the game's ID, so there's no room for mistakes.

This code can be improved a lot, but it will get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, can you elaborate on the good practice as well? Cheers

Comment: You know, maybe it's because I misread the question, you're repeating the submit button in each loop so you're submitting one pair of fields each time. I'll fix my answer!